# How to find eigenvalues and eigenspace of a standard matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$T : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is the reflection about the line $y = x$.

I know that to find the eigenvalues, you must find the characteristic equation of the transformation, but how do I find the eigenspace of the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably best answered without any computations, but instead using a concrete understanding of the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

If $T$ is a linear transformation, and there is some non-zero vector $v$ and scalar $\lambda$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$, then we say that $v$ is an eigenvector for $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  In other words, $v$ is an eigenvalue for $T$ if upon applying $T$ to it, the result is the same as if we were to just scale the vector by $\lambda$.

Can you think of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that when you reflect it across the line $y=x$, you obtain a scalar multiple of what you started with?  Recall that multiplying by positive scalars changes the magnitude of a vector, but not its direction, and multiplying by negative scalars will cause the vector to point in the opposite direction.  Hint: there are two "types" of eigenvectors in your example, each giving rise to a different eigenvalue.